# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}}}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}}}$$

How to evaluate the above integral? I am trying this question by substituting $x = \tan^{2 / 3} y$. Then the denominator will become $$\sqrt{\tan^{2/3} y+\sqrt{\tan^{4/3} y+ \tan y}} .$$ But how to proceed further?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think factorizing the denominator first will make it easier to choose a more suitable trigonometric substitution.$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^3}}}=\sqrt x\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt x}}}$$

Comment: Mathematica returns the integral untouched.

Comment: $x=\tan^4y$ is better?

Comment: From which source is this question from?

Comment: @BobDobbs. Thans for the idea ! Cheers :-)

Comment: The best approximation I could deduce is this $\approx 1.1574160236587041$

Answer (score 8):

Using the rewrite from @user170231, consider the substitution $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \sinh^2 t$

$$I = \int_{\sinh^{-1}(1)}^\infty \frac{4\cosh t\:dt}{\sinh^3 t\sqrt{1+\cosh t}}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\sinh^{-1}(1)}^\infty\frac{\cosh\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\sinh^3\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\cosh^3\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}+\frac{\sinh\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}{\sinh^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\cosh^4\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}\:\frac{dt}{2}$$

Notice that the integrand is almost a product rule. Using the interchange $t\leftrightarrow \frac{t}{2}$ we can split the integral up as

$$I = \color{green}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{-1}{\sinh^2t \cosh^3t}\right]_{\cosh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}}}^\infty}$$

$$ - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{\cosh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}}}^\infty \frac{(1-\tanh^2 t)\operatorname{sech}^2t}{\sinh t}dt$$

$$= \color{green}{2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}+\color{red}{\frac{\operatorname{sech} t}{6\sqrt{2}}\left(2+\operatorname{sech}^2 t\right)\Biggr|_{t=\operatorname{sech}^{-1}\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}}}$$

$$-\color{blue}{\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}\int_{\cosh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}}}^\infty \frac{3\sinh t}{\cosh^2 t - 1}-\tanh t \operatorname{sech}t\:dt}$$

$$= \color{green}{2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}} + \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}}{3}} + \color{blue}{\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}\Biggr[3\coth^{-1}(\cosh t)-\operatorname{sech}t\Biggr]_{\operatorname{sech}^{-1}\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}}^\infty}$$

Crunching the numbers, we get a final analytic answer of

$$I = \boxed{\color{green}{2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}} + \color{purple}{\frac{\sqrt{5\sqrt{2}-1}}{6}} - \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-2}}\approx 1.157416}$$

Comment: So much stress because I forgot $\coth^{-1}(\infty) = 0$ and not $1$... ‍♂️

Comment: Another nice solution !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you! I have attempted to color code the solution to make it clear which parts of the equation contribute to which terms (with purple = red + blue)

Comment: Now : nice + beautiful (even if I cannot fully appreciate). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 6):

A few substitutions pave the way for a fairly simple partial fraction expansion:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}}} \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt x \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac1{\sqrt x}}}} \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\frac1y}}} \tag1 \\
&= 4 \int_{\sqrt2}^\infty \frac{z}{\left(z^2-1\right)^2 \sqrt{z+1}} \, dz \tag2 \\
&= 8 \int_{\sqrt{\sqrt2+1}}^\infty \frac{w^2-1}{w^4 \left(w^2-2\right)^2} \, dw \tag3
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ $y = \sqrt x$
- $(2)$ $z=\sqrt{\dfrac{y+1}y}$
- $(3)$ $w=\sqrt{z+1}$

Comment: Instead of the $z$-substitution, you could find the inverse of the function in $y$ which is very neat! [Here's why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: I deleted my ridiculous answer. Congratulations for making it ! and (+1)

Comment: How did a positive integral become negaive?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I like your numerical answers and tables, they make convergence issues quite clear

Comment: @BobDobbs sign error in step $(2)$, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet an other solution, obtained by rewriting the integral as an integral on the appropriate curve $C$. The reason why we "can integrate" becomes transparent, this curve $C$ turns out to have "by chance" genus zero.

---

Let us denote by $y$ the radical in the denominator, then exhibit an algebraic relation between $x$ and $y$. We have after successive transformations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
y &= \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}}\ ,\\
y^2 - x &= \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}\ ,\\
(y^2 - x)^2 &= x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}\ ,\\
y^4 - 2y^2x &= \sqrt{x^3}\ ,\\
y^4(y^2 - 2x)^2 - x^3 &= 0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we have to integrate $dx/y$ on the curve $C$ with algebraic equation given by the last line above from the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$ to the point $(x,y)=(1,\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2})$. Since $\sqrt2$ and its cousin will appear relatively often, let us introduce the notations:
$$
\bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad
\begin{aligned}
a &=\sqrt 2\ ,\\
b &=\sqrt{a-1}=\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}\ .
\end{aligned}
\qquad
}
$$
It turns out that the curve $C$ is rational, (it has genus zero,) and we can ask the computer for a rational parametrization, code is postponed. A version of the offered parametrization is
$$
\bbox[lightblue]{
\qquad
x = \frac{u^8}{(1-2u^2)^2}\ ,\qquad
y = \frac {u^3}{1-2u^2}\ ,\qquad u\in[0, b]\ ,
\qquad
}
$$
and it is easy to check that
$y = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}}$, the one needed intermediate step showing this, starting from the formula for $x$, being
$\sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}=
\frac{u^6(1-u^2)}{(1-2u^2)^2}$.
Performing the above $x$-substitution we have for the given integral $J$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &:=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x^3}}}}
=\int_
{\substack{
C\\
\text{from }(x,y)=(0,\ 0)\\
\text{to }(x,y)=(1, \ 1/b)}}
\ \frac{dx}y
\\
&=
\int_0^b\frac{8u^4(1-u^2)}{(1-2u^2)^2}\; du
=
\int_0^b\left[\frac1{(1-2u^2)^2} - \frac1{1-2u^2}-2u^2\right]\; du
\\
&=
\bbox[lightyellow]{\ 
\frac 16(13+2a)b
+\frac a4\log(a+1)
+\frac a4\log(1-ab)
\ }
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

(The above handy formula will be checked numerically in the second note.)

---

*Note:* Computer aid:

```
sage: x, y = QQ['x,y'].gens()
....: C = Curve(y^4*(y^2 - 2*x)^2 - x^3)
sage: 
sage: C.genus()
0
sage: C.rational_parameterization()
Scheme morphism:
  From: Affine Space of dimension 1 over Rational Field
  To:   Affine Plane Curve over Rational Field defined by y^8 - 4*x*y^6 + 4*x^2*y^4 - x^3
  Defn: Defined on coordinates by sending (t) to
        (1/(t^8 - 4*t^6 + 4*t^4), (-1)/(t^3 - 2*t))
```

And we took $u=1/t$ instead.

*Note:* Computer check, pari/gp:

```
? intnum(x=0, 1, 1/sqrt(x + sqrt(x^2 + sqrt(x^3))))
%1 = 1.1574160236587956204374053042986128629
? a = sqrt(2);
? b = sqrt(a - 1);
? (13 + 2*a)*b/6 + a/4*log(a + 1) + a/4*log(1 - a*b)
%6 = 1.1574160236587956204374053042986128635
```

Comment: It turns out that also other integrals of the shape $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^A + \sqrt{x^B + \sqrt{x^C}}}}$$ lead to integrals of rational functions, since the related curve of equation $$((y^2 - x^A)^2 - x^B)^2 - x^C=0$$ has genus zero. This happens for instance for the triples $(A,B,C)$ in the following list:$$(1,2,3)\\(1,2,5)\\(2,4,7)\\(2,4,9)\\(3,6,11)\\(3,6,13)\\(4,8,15)\\\vdots$$However, the corresponding integrals from the resulted rational functions...